# Too high background image on Ipad4

Tags: css, ipad, background

When I launch the website on Ipad4 (portrait resolution) the body background img is too high, the same as the section (the height is set to 100vh).

What can I do to make the background shorter?

Below I attach link to the website:

http://uptoclouds.pl/miniporadnik/pazdziernik2015/

I guess there are some other bugs but after 2 months of learning this is my first website (other hints are more than welcome).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (workaround for iPad)

```
/** 
 * iPad with portrait orientation.
 */

@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  section {
    height: 1024px;
  }
}
```

You can also add `margin: 0` to `body` tag and delete `margin-top: -8px` from section.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work out (check img below)               http://uptoclouds.pl/miniporadnik/pazdziernik2015/img/ipad.PNG